# How can I pass parameters in an Angular.js Controller to a Resource?

Tags: angularjs

So I have the following controller where I inject a constant, APIKEY.

```
myApp.controller('JobsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Jobs', 'APIKEY', function($scope, Jobs, apiKey) {
  var promise = Jobs.query().$promise;
  // do more awesome programming
}
```

I want to pass the apiKey to the following service but can't figure out for the life of me how to do it.

```
myApp.factory('Jobs', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/someurl/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
    query: { method: 'GET', headers: {'Authorization': apiKey} }
  });
}]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: inject it as dependency the same way you do with `$resource`

Answer (score 7):

Wrap your Jobs $resource inside another function:

```js
myApp.factory('Jobs', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return function(apiKey){
    return $resource('/someurl/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
      query: { method: 'GET', headers: {'Authorization': apiKey} }
    });
  }
}]);

myApp.controller('JobsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Jobs', 'APIKEY', function($scope, Jobs, apiKey) {
  var promise = Jobs('MY_KEY').query().$promise;
  // do more awesome programming
}
```

Comment: @Stewie but surely someone can just view the source code on the webpage and view the APIKey in the source file? Then use the APIKey to gain access to the API endpoints

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at the [provide service API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide).

```
$provide.constant('APIKEY', 'theHash');
```

and then inject it into the controllers and services (for instance, when you create the service and inject dependencies into it).

Comment: fairly apparent in OP question that he's already registered the apiKey and is already using dependency injection for it